# Get all directories comma separated and send output to other script

Tags: linux, bash

We use phpDocumentator to document our php code.
The php code is in different dictionaries. 
The script which runs the phpDocumentator looks like this:

```
./phpdoc -d dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4
```

Every time we add a new directory, I have to add this one to the script.

I would like to do this dynamically.

```
ls -d ../*test*
```

this lists all needed directories but space separated and not comma separated.

**Question:**

How can I list the directories comma separated?

how can I add this list as -d parameter to the phpdoc script?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `ls -dm */` to generate a comma-separated list of directories. `-d` will return directories only and `-m` will output to a comma-separated list.

You could then store the output in a variable and pass it along as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_DIRECTORY=/some/directory
FOLDERS=`ls -dm $MY_DIRECTORY/*/ | tr -d ' '`
phpdoc -d $FOLDERS
```

Comment: As given in the example the list of directories shall not contain spaces.

Comment: `-d` does not _limit_ `ls`'s output to directories; it simply prevents `ls` from _descending into_ directories.

Answer (score 5):

No need to call an external program (assuming bash or ksh93):

```
var=(../*test*)
IFS=','
phpdoc -d "${var[*]}"
```

See @mklement0's comment below.  The problem with this solution is that it will find filenames as well as directories, therefore:

```
var=(../*test*/)            # trailing / ensures directories only
IFS=','
phpdoc -d "${var[*]/%/}"    # remove the trailing / from the names
```

The solution involving expansion on all array elements is @mklement0's (except there is no need to escape the /).

Comment: An elegant solution for using `,` as the separator, but `../*test*` could potentially match _files_ too; a simple fix to ensure that only _directories_ are matched is to use `../*test*/` instead.
However, that adds a trailing `/` to all matches too; if that's not acceptable, more work is needed.

Comment: @mklement0 well done at picking that up after 3 years!  You are right, and I'll consider it...

Comment: Solution edited.  If only GLOBIGNORE supported any condition instead of just a pattern...

Comment: Thanks for updating; yes, POSIX-like shells make it surprisingly difficult to filter by filesystem type. Removing the trailing `/` from the globbing results of `../*test/` is easy, however: Bash allows you to perform substitutions on all elements of an array with a single parameter expansion: `phpdoc -d "${var[*]/%\/}"`

Comment: @mklement0:  I didn't know that parameter expansion worked on all elements of an array (tested on 3.2).  Thank-you for that!

Comment: My pleasure - it's a powerful feature, but not frequently seen and therefore easy to forget (as I had, until our exchange jogged my memory). Good to know that escaping the `/` is optional in this case, but it's worth pointing out that it _is_ needed for nonempty _substitutions_ of `/` (as opposed to mere _removal_); e.g., `var='12/'; echo "${var/%\//!}"` yields `12!`, as expected, but `var='12/'; echo "${var/%//!}"` yields `12//!`

Comment: @mklement0:  the \ wasn't doing any harm, and there is a case to say that "if in doubt, escape it".  As a common default delimiter, / is often escaped, but I had to give *some* input :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is simpler way using `find` and `paste`:

```
dirs=$(find . -type d | paste -d, -s)
```

and the same, but using absolute paths:

```
dirs=$(find "$PWD" -type d | paste -d, -s)
```

and version with `tr`:

```
dirs=$(find . -type d -print0 | tr '\0' ',')
```

<sup>Above will scan folders recursively, unless you'll add `-maxdepth 1` to list only one level deep.</sup>

then run `phpdoc` as:

```
./phpdoc -d "$dirs"
```

Comment: ++ for truly only matching _directories_ (except _symlinks to_ directories), but please double-quote `$PWD`, and don't use all-caps variable names; quibble: unless you add `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`, `.` is also matched, as wells as any grandchildren directories and below.

Answer (score 1):

```
./phpdoc -d $(ls -dm ../*test* | tr -d ' ')
```

Comment: this one works too. thanks. also here I had to add `| tr -d '\n'`